# Is there any way to keep Android Emulator Inside VS Code Window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I prefer to work on Fullscreen in MacBook. But since the Android Emulator is a seperate window, keeping full screen makes me to swipe between pages. I  want to keep my VS code in full screen mode.

I want to have the Android EMulator inside VS Code like Android Studio or IntelliJ Studio.